# Error "Relative branch out of reach" in avr

Tags: embedded, avr

I'm new on AVR. I have an "Relative branch out of reach" error for the "brne    round_loop" line while debugging. Is anyone to help me? Thank you so much for your helps.

```
; Test if round counter has reached 14
mov     t4, rc
subi    t4, 14
brne    round_loop
```

round_loop:

```
round_loop:
; XOR state and key
eor     s0, k0
eor     s1, k1
eor     s2, k2
eor     s3, k3
```

Comment: Do you really men "while debugging", or rather while building for debug?  It is not possible for the assembler to generate BRNE opcode with an out of reach offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AVR [`BRNE`](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_BRNE.html) instruction is a 16 bit op-code, 7 bits of which are the branch offset. This 7 bit signed operand can have a value *k* in the range *-64 ≤ k ≤ +63*. The PC is modified by *k +1* (i.e. -63 to +64). If the jump is further then that, a relative branch is unsuitable.

You either need to locate the target closer to the branch, or use an unconditional branch to an unconditional jump (JMP) with a 22bit range, or a relative jump (RJMP) with a 12 bit range.

```
  mov     t4, rc
  subi    t4, 14

  brne    round_loop_longjmp
  rjmp    no_round_jmp
round_loop_longjmp:
  rjmp    round_loop

no_round_jmp:
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

A relative branch means that the jump occurs by changing the position of the program counter(which instruction is being executed right now) by either adding or subtracting a value from it. That means round_loop in brne is not translated into an absolute address, but a distance from the current instruction. The limit for brne is 7bits, so I believe it should be within +-64 words(each instruction is 1 word so 64 instructions). So the round_loop label should be within 64 instructions of the brne instruction, either before or after it.

If you can't move round_loop within that range then you'll have to do a branch to a label that will do a JMP to round_loop.

Comment: It might be that the debugger inserted extra code for its own purposes, moving a previously in-range branch out of range.

Comment: Good answer, but note that the number of words is not necessarily equal to the number of instructions;instructions with 16 or 22 bit address operands (such as JMP for example) are *two words*.  Also a minor point; the range of a 7 bit signed operand is -64 to +63 rather then +/-64, and the operation BRNE performs PC = PC + k + 1 when the condition is true, the jump range is -63 to +64.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
mov     t4, rc
subi    t4, 14
in      r16,SREG
sbrs    r16,1 ;bit 1 ZERO FLAG
rjmp    round_loop
```